# Is there an app to control preferences/desktop/dock based on an environment

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, high-sierra

I use my laptop for personal use and work. Is there a way to be able to reconfigure my preferences, desktop icons, and dock apps with a script or app?

I personally would like something like f.lux where the settings can change based on the time, so I can set something like work mode between 9a-5pm.

Comment: One way is to create separate users for work and personal. ControlPlane is a utility that could maybe do what you want on the fly, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just create a new user, and just sign on to whichever one depending on where you are.

Comment: While technically this can work, IMO it's hardly an ideal way to deal with the issue. This approach can have issues with software licensed explicitly to a single user that validates the user hasn't changed. User data by default ends up in two different Home folders, which can have permission issues even when both accounts are admin, etc. Personally I have AppleScripts that reset things base on the environment, i.e. I have a MBP that I use by itself and also attached to a 27" TB Display. I need some things different between the two and handle it programmatically vs manually changing things.

Comment: @user3439894 How do you do this programmatically?

Comment: @Scott I know of this solution, but I rather not have to set shared things up twice. I want to be able to use both environments during my work time and hide somethings and change some settings after a certain time of day.

Comment: @Michael Ozeryansky, You asked, "How do you do this programmatically?", well that's a rather broad question that I can't adequately answer in a 600 character limit comment! As a general rule, anything I have to do repetitively I create a programatic solution for using different programming languages and or third party utilities along with what's built into the OS. From my beginning days of computing I've implemented solutions to avoid manual repetitive actions wherever reasonably possible by whatever means are available, while learning whatever I had to along the way to accomplish the goal.

Comment: @user3439894 I meant which APIs/Libraries/etc have you used to assist in automating desktop management, not how to do anything programmatically, ha. I'll have to dig around on the cocoa APIs.